# C# ItextSharp Fontawesome Icons ( currency ) - PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, icons, itext

i have problem is importing the icons (fontawesome-webfont.ttf) and showing them on PDF -but i am unable to show them on the PDF especialy currency icon (fa-money) some of the icons i was able to get it from the CultureInfo class if any thing i missed apart from this

```
chunkRows = new Chunk(val.ToString("C", new CultureInfo(strCulture)) + "  ", rowFont);
```

How can i solve this problem needed help

Code---

```
var fontAwesomeIcon = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontpath + "fontawesome-webfont.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

Font fontAwe = new Font(fontAwesomeIcon,8,Font.NORMAL,Color.BLACK);

chunkRows = new Chunk("\f0d6", fontAwe);
```

Comment: Why are you using `CP1252`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please adapt your code like this:

```
var fontAwesomeIcon = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontpath + "fontawesome-webfont.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font fontAwe = new Font(fontAwesomeIcon, 8);
chunkRows = new Chunk("\uf0d6", fontAwe);
```

The result will look like this:

[image]

Comment: I am still not able to see the Icon @BrunoLowagie

Comment: Which version of iTextSharp are you using? Somebody posted a similar problem on StackOverflow a while ago. The problem disappeared after upgrading to an official version of iTextSharp (instead of using a version that wasn't endorsed by iText Group NV).

Comment: Also: I copy/pasted some code from your question, but now that I took a close look at it, I see that you omitted the `u` in `"\uf0d6"` (you have "\f0d6").

Comment: Thanks a lot Correct , In my project i was using 4.1.2.0, I am able to the icon in my dumy project  version ( 5.5.4 ) after adding "\uf0d6"  but if i have to make it generic for all the icons i should add the "u" for all the icon class ( curious )

Comment: When you use hardcoded UNICODE `String`s, you need to use the `\u` notation. Please upgrade to a more recent version! iTextSharp 4.1.2.0 shouldn't be used in a commercial context due to several technical and legal problems with the code base.

Comment: @JG'sSpark Commenting on a question that is more than 3 years old is not a good idea. Please post a new question if you have a problem. Also note that iText was completely rewritten in the last couple of years. The version that is discussed in this question and answer is no longer supported. The current version is iText 7.1.3.