# FontAwesome Icons won't Show on Generated PDF using mPDF

Tags: php, pdf, icons, mpdf

I am using mPDF in generating payslips. However, the icons in the payslip aren't showing once it is generated. It only leaves a blank space just like this:

[image]

Icons should show on those highlighted spots. 
So far, here's what I've done:

I am using Yii2 PHP framework and here's my action controller:

```
public function actionPdf($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $earnings = EarningDetails::find()->where(['payslip_id' => $model->_id, 'status' => 1])->all();
    $deductions = DeductionDetails::find()->where(['payslip_id' => $model->_id, 'status' => 1])->all();
    $html = $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $model,
        'earnings' => $earnings,
        'deductions' => $deductions,
    ]);
    $mpdf = new mPDF('c','A5-L','0','',0,4,1,1,0,0);
    $mpdf->allow_charset_conversion = true; 
    $mpdf->charset_in = 'windows-1252';
    $mpdf->SetTopMargin(0);
    $user_password = User::find()->where(['_id' => $model->user_id ])->one(); 
    $password = $user_password->fname.$user_password->lname;
    $mpdf->SetProtection(array(), $password, $password);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Output('Payslip.pdf', 'D');
    exit;        
}
```

Am I missing something? Please let me know.

Comment: As explained in my answer to [C# ItextSharp Fontawesome Icons ( currency ) - PDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30440982/c-sharp-itextsharp-fontawesome-icons-currency-pdf), you're using *Windows-1252* encoding for symbols that probably require UNICODE.

Comment: so what do you mean? the question is related to c# though

Comment: It's in French, but take a look at the screen shots in this blog: [Utilisation de polices: PDF et iText](http://www.developpez.net/forums/blogs/133351-blowagie/b521/utilisation-polices-pdf-itext/). You see that some characters are missing in some screen shots because the wrong encoding is used. There is a difference between the double-byte Unicode character `\uf0d6` and the two separate single byte characters with value 240 (`0xF0`) and 214 (`0xD6`). Maybe that's causing your problem.

Comment: Sorry but I don't really understand. what do you suggest I do?

Comment: You could start to learn more about fonts and encoding. Show us the PDF. Maybe you're not even using the Fontawesome font (chances are that it doesn't show up in the Fonts panel under Document > Properties).

Comment: The PDF is the screenshot I posted in my question above. I checked the Fonts panel, it only has the Roboto Slab font. But fontawesome is already in my system. Maybe I missed something while importing it to pdf? I don't know

Comment: Fonts like Fontawesome ALWAYS need to be embedded. The fact that it's missing in your Fonts panel is proof that (1) you aren't embedding it, and (2) you aren't even using it! No wonder the icons don't appear in your text!

Answer (score 7):

Encoding issues aside, this could be a couple of things. Firstly, you need to integrate FontAwesome with your MPDF installation. Secondly, you need to consider how you're speficiying the glyph in HTML.

### Installing FontAwesome in mPDF

Download or clone FontAwesome from https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome and copy *fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf* into your MPDF *ttfonts/* directory.

In your MDPF *config_fonts.php* file, add the following lines to `$this->fontdata`:

```
 /* FontAwesome */
    "fontawesome" => array(
        'R' => "fontawesome-webfont.ttf"
        ),
```

### Adding the glyph in HTML

You need to keep in mind that the CSS `:before` pseudo-selector commonly used to add FontAwesome glyphs to HTML doesn't work in mPDF.

**Bad:**

```
<i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>
```

... because this FontAwesome CSS rule doesn't work in mPDF:

```
.fa-smile-o:before {
  content: "\f118";
}
```

**Good:**

```
<i class="fa">&#xf118;</i>
```

You can get the unicode code point for each glyph by clicking on it on the FontAwesome Icon List, but the [Cheatsheet](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/) is more convenient for this.

Comment: This answer just saved my night. Thank you. I wish mpdf had this worked out a bit better.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use the re-mapped fontawesome 4.7 (free) font to #0021-#02E5 characters,
and use it as it was regular FONT (ascii).

**You can download the ready-to-use font here:**
http://mdb-blog.blogspot.com/2021/12/using-fontwesome-in-php-fpdf.html

```
Note that the example works for FPDF, but it is easly can be made for any tool :)
```