# Font awesome icon not showing in generated PDF in Laravel blade

Tags: html, css, laravel, pdf, font-awesome

I have used the Font Awesome icons in HTML which works fine. But when I generate PDF of this HTML, all CSS and HTML working fine, only Font Awesome icon not showing.

```php
$pdf = PDF2::loadView('templates.'.$request->template_code, ['section' => $section])
    ->setOption('page-size', 'A4')
    ->setOption('margin-bottom', '0mm')
    ->setOption('margin-top', '0mm')
    ->setOption('margin-right', '0mm')
    ->setOption('margin-left', '0mm');

$fileName = 'resumes/'.str_slug($section['info']['data']['first_name']).'-'.$user->id.'.pdf';

Storage::disk('public')->put($fileName, $pdf->output());

return Storage::disk('public')->url($fileName);
```

Here I generate a PDF in a Laravel controller and use Font Awesome icon like this in the blade.

```
<i class="fa fa-star checked"></i>
```

I am using Font Awesome CDN version. How can I show icons in my pdf?

Comment: Cdn font won't work inside pdf, add font awesome [link](https://github.com/angujo/laravel-pdf-2) custom font

Comment: hope help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30453168/fontawesome-icons-wont-show-on-generated-pdf-using-mpdf

Comment: @MohammadMalek i have tried with that solution. not working for me

Comment: @kerbholz that will be in pdf

Answer (score 2):

u need to add **fontawesome** using inline style add in html `<head>` tag in your blade

```
<style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'fontawesome3';
        src: url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0') format('truetype');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
    .fa3 {
        display: inline-block;
        font: normal normal normal 14px/1 fontawesome3;
        text-rendering: auto;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    }

</style>
```

and then used by prefix  **`fa3`** in your blad

```
<i class="fa3 fa-star checked"></i>
```